# How to send a session scoped attribute through jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

I have an issue I have this jQuery code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#follow").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url:'/tweety-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/twitter/tiles/follow',
                data:{
                        searchedUser: $('#searchedUser').val()
                }   
        })
    })
})
```

this piece of code get hidden id and send it's value to the following method in my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/follow",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody void followUser(@RequestParam("searchedUser") String userToFollow, 
            @ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
            if(userToFollow.equals(user.getUsername())){
                // do nothing
            }else{
                service.followUser(userToFollow,user.getUsername());
            }
    }
```

I want to send a session scoped attribute through the previous ajax call. Any clue on how doing that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to have that attribute's value in a hidden input field somewhere on the page, so you can then read it in with jQuery.
Unforunately, to the best of my knowledge jQuery or javascript does not have access to request, session or application scope variables.

So, if you do something like this:

```
<input type='hidden' name='${sessionVarName}' value='${sessionVarValue}' id='sessionVar'/>
```

You can access it after the page loads like this:

```
$(function(){
  var sessionVar = $('#sessionVar').val();
  alert(sessionVar);
});
```

This is the solution I've used when needing to get tomcat session vars into javascript, the method should work for you too.

Hope this helps

Comment: I did so and it gave me EL Exception however I redeployed my project and the previous code worked just fine.

Comment: you would need to edit the hidden input markup, as i stated in the answer this was only pseudocode as i do not know the language you are using, only jQuery. the method of placing the value of your var on the page as a hidden input and then reading it with javascript should work fine, you just needed to code it in spring.

Comment: oh actually I didn't realise it was java. i used to do this with JSPs, all you need to do is replace the name and value attributes of that input with something that will echo them onto the page

Answer (score 0):

I suggest u to send a AttributeName which will successfully make u to get the sessionScope Attribute,that will be simple.